# How to call the contract function after a specified interval

Tags: solidity

There is a function in contract that should call every month. Can this be implemented with the help of Solidity?

For example:

> I have made an order for 1 month. A month later the status of the
>   order was changed automatically.
>
> Or every month, the contract variable must increase by 1

Comment: ethereum smart contracts' functions are event based, they will never execute if you never trigger them. the easy way is to have a server do the automatic change of your status.

Answer (score 0):

No, transactions can't be scheduled for the future.

But the examples you gave can be implemented without the need to make an explicit state change. E.g. for the order status:

```
function createOrder() public {
    creationTime = now;
}

function orderStatus() view returns (OrderStatus) {
    if (now < creationTime + 30 days) {
        return OrderStatus.InProgress;
    } else {
        return OrderStatus.Finished;
    }
}
```

or for the counter case:

```
uint256 startTime = now;

function howManyMonths() public view returns (uint256) {
    return (now - startTime) / 30 days;
}
```